# Multiples Update con un Select y condicionales en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, update

necesito ayuda con una actualización en mi base de datos mysql explico lo que nesecito hacer:

1-tengo una tabla llamada detalle_nomina la cual necesito hacer un update sobre los registros que cumplan la siguiente condición: Nomina_idNomina=1 and catalogo_Codigo='0103' y la Cedula del empleado que correspondan a todos los empleados que encuentre. anexo imagen con las filas seleccionadas de los registros que deseo actualizar, claro tomando en cuenta que pueden ser mas de 70 empleados distintos para el ejemplo uso 2:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el campo que necesito actualizar es Monto_Personal y Monto_Empresa de la tabla detalle_nomina pero antes debo sumar la columna Monto_Personal y multiplicarla por 0.01  donde catalogo_Codigo sea una asignacion y Nomina_idNomina=1 que es la que estoy trabajando para eso hago un inner join y su condicional aqui añadire el codigo donde logro realizar dicha operacion :

```
SELECT
    d.Nomina_idNomina,
    d.Cedula,0103 as catalogo_Codigo,
    sum(d.Monto_Personal)*0.01 as Ingresos
FROM
    detalle_nomina d inner join catalogo c on d.catalogo_Codigo=c.Codigo
where c.Asignacion=true and d.Nomina_idNomina=1 group by d.Cedula;
```

Este es el resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hasta aqui voy bien esos son los montos que necesito para actualizar, e intentado hacerlo con el siguiente fragmento de codigo y funciona pero me da un error:

```
UPDATE
    detalle_nomina AS dest,
    (
    SELECT
        d.Nomina_idNomina,
        d.Cedula,
      0103 as catalogo_Codigo,
        sum(d.Monto_Personal)*0.01 as Ingresos
    FROM
      detalle_nomina d inner join catalogo c on d.catalogo_Codigo=c.Codigo
    where c.Asignacion=true and d.Nomina_idNomina=1 group by d.Cedula
    ) AS src
SET
    dest.Monto_Personal = src.Ingresos
WHERE
    dest.Nomina_idNomina = src.Nomina_idNomina and dest.Cedula=src.Cedula and dest.catalogo_Codigo=src.catalogo_Codigo
;
```

este es el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

bueno si alguien puede ayudarme con esto, o hacerlo de una mejor manera estaria muy agradecido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema es que la columna "Monto_Personal" está siendo truncada ya que está recibiendo más de 4 caracteres. Intenta con aumentar el tamaño que puede recibir tal columna.

Comment: Eso lo viste en la imagen, en el _at row 4_ ?